# Error on UIPicker TitleforRow

Tags: ios, uipickerview

Good day all,
I am working on a program that involves using a UIPickerview. This worked fine but, instead of setting the array in my ViewdidLoad I am downloading it from my webserverice and saving it to my array. Seems to work fine but calling `titleforRow`  on  `return _pickerData[row];` is giving an error. `[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector` Im not  sure why, it seems to me that I am assigning the values to the _pickerData incorrectly but, all the known methods i attempted is failing
Would like if I coould get a bit of assistance.
Thank you

This is my code.

```
-(void)getMyItems:(NSArray *)items
{
      /* This works
      _pickerData = @[@"test"];
      [_uiPickerController  reloadAllComponents];
      */
      /* This doesnt work
    _pickerData = items;
    [_uiPickerController  reloadAllComponents];
   */


    for(int i=0;i<[items count];i++)
    {
    Details*bObject = [items objectAtIndex:i];
    if(bObject)
    {
         NSLog(@"list%@",[[items objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"name"]);// This list all items in my array
        _pickerData=[[items objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"name"];//but it is not getting assigned to _pickData Array

    }

    }


     [_uiPickerController  reloadAllComponents]; //This gives error when run uncommented.

}
```

**Update - ITEMS ARRAY**

```
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];


        Details*downloadobject = [[Detailsalloc] init];
        downloadobject .name = jsonElement[@"name"];



        [_transferArray addObject:downloadobject ]; (transfer array is an array
    }
if (self.delegate)
    {
        [self.delegate getMyItems:_transferArray ];
    }
```

**NSlog shows**

```
2014-09-28 01:07:05.002 progb[5647:a0b] list catapid
2014-09-28 01:07:05.002 progb[5647:a0b] list metaphod
2014-09-28 01:07:05.002 progb[5647:a0b] list butterfree
2014-09-28 01:07:05.002 progb[5647:a0b] list beedrill
2014-09-28 01:07:05.002 progb[5647:a0b] list genesect
2014-09-28 01:07:05.002 progb[5647:a0b] list nincada
2014-09-28 01:07:05.003 progb[5647:a0b] list ledian
2014-09-28 01:07:05.003 progb[5647:a0b] list dustox
2014-09-28 01:07:05.003 progb[5647:a0b] list shuckle
```

Comment: What does your log show -- add the actual printout from one pass through your for loop.

Comment: @rdelmar I have added it to the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're defining your array is incorrect. You're defining it as [[items objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"name"] which I'm guessing is a string, and in every pass through the for loop, you redefine it as another string. So, when your loop exits, _pickerData will contain the last string, not an array. You should make _pickerData a mutable array, instantiate it outside the loop, then add objects to it in the for loop.

```
_pickerData = [NSMutableArray new];
for(Details *bObject in _items) {
   [_pickerData addObject: [bObject valueForKey:@"name"]]; // You should be able to use bObject.name here instead of using valueForKey: if you import Details.h into this class
}
```

Comment: i dont seem to have this correct. I made _pickerData NSMutable in my interface, then are you saying the way I am assigning values to it in the for loop should work now? secondly even before I attempted that method _pickerData=_items did not work for me

Comment: @SleepParalysis, no that's not what I said. You need to instantiate the mutable array outside the for loop, then use addObject: to add each string as you loop.